# Desarrollo local de react

Tags: reactjs

estoy haciendo [ejercicios de react en codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/paths/build-web-apps-with-react/tracks/bwa-intro-to-react/modules/react-101-jsx-u/lessons/react-jsx-advanced/exercises/jsx-conditionals-valid-if) y me surgió la inquietud de correr el ejercicio localmente.

Pero mi navegador muestra el error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Este es mi código:

```js
// app.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function coinToss() {
    // This function will randomly return either 'heads' or 'tails'.
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
}

const pics = {
    kitty: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-kitty.jpg',
    doggy: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-puppy.jpeg'
};
let img;

// if/else statement begins here:
if (coinToss() === "heads"){
    img = <img src={pics.kitty} />
} else{
    img = <img src={pics.doggy} />
}

ReactDOM.render(img, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
/* styles .css*/
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#app {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#app div {
    width: 100%;
}

#app div div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#app div div div {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

h1, h2 {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav a {
    margin:12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
}

button {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    background-color: #F4595B;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C24648;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #FF7375;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C24648;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

button:active {
    background-color: #C24648;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C24648;
    color: #CCC;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Learn ReactJS</title>
</head>

<body>
<main id="app"></main>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

¿Cómo debo modificar mis archivos para poder mostrar el ejemplo en mi navegador?

---

He intentado por sugerencia estos cambios sin éxito

```js
// app.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function coinToss() {
  // This function will randomly return either 'heads' or 'tails'.
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
}

const pics = {
  kitty: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-kitty.jpg',
  doggy: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-puppy.jpeg'
};
let img;

// if/else statement begins here:
if (coinToss() === "heads") {
  img = ( <
    img src = {
      pics.kitty
    }
    />
  );
  />
} else {
  img = ( <
    img src = {
      pics.doggy
    }
    />
  );
  />
}

ReactDOM.render(img, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
/* styles .css*/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#app div {
  width: 100%;
}

#app div div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

#app div div div {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a {
  margin: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
}

button {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  background-color: #F4595B;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #C24648;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #FF7375;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #C24648;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #C24648;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #C24648;
  color: #CCC;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <title>Learn ReactJS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sustituye <main id="app"></main> por <div id="app"> </div>

Comment: @MiguelZarate mismo error

Comment: La declaracion de importacion de scripts van en el Header algo asi <head>
     <script src="js/react.production.min.js"></script>

Comment: y tu variable img debe tener parentesis img = (<img src={pics.kitty} />);//

Comment: @MiguelZarate nada de eso sirvió :C

Answer (score 0):

Tras un rato lo pude solucionar, espero le sirva a alguien

Primeramente cambié la extensión de mi `js` a `.jsx` ya que no era un javascript normal y agregué `JSXTransformer`.

Mi HTML quedó asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Learn ReactJS</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0-alpha1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="app.jsx"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

mi jsx quedó así:

```
function coinToss() {
    // This function will randomly return either 'heads' or 'tails'.
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
}

const pics = {
    kitty: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-kitty.jpg',
    doggy: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-puppy.jpeg'
};
let img;

// if/else statement begins here:
if (coinToss() === "heads") {
    img = (
        <img src={pics.kitty} alt="kitty"/>
    );
} else {
    img = (
        <img src={pics.doggy} alt="doggy"/>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(img, document.getElementById('app'));
```

es decir, sin los require.

Para mi caso en particular como los corrí en Chrome me daba error porque todo estaba en localhost y el archivo se carga fon protocolo `file://`, así que usé mi [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) para correrlo.